# Undefined in the following when returning object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function with this in:

```
1:  var object = get_resource($scope, CbgenRestangular, $stateParams.scheme_id);
2:  console.log(object)
```

Which runs this:

```
get_resource = function ($scope, CbgenRestangular, id){
    CbgenRestangular.one('scheme', id).get().then(function(object){
             console.log(object)
        return object
    })
},
```

My issue is that within `get_resource` function `console.log` returns the object perfect, however line 2 in the above code it's `undefined`, why?

This should be the same object thats in the `get_resource` function, why is it undefined when I return it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get_resource` doesn't have a return statement, so it's no surprise that you get `undefined` as a result. You do have a return statement inside the function that you pass to the `then` function, but this doesn't return from the "outer" function.

What you are dealing with here, are promises. The `get` function apparently returns a promise:

```
var promise = CbgenRestangular.one('scheme', id).get();
```

To get the result of that promise, you can use the `then` function, as you did inside the `get_resource` function.

Now, if you want to handle that promise outside of this function, you can simple return the promise and then do the same thing:

```
get_resource = function ($scope, CbgenRestangular, id){
    return CbgenRestangular.one('scheme', id).get().then(function(object){
             console.log(object)
        return object
    })
}, 

//.....

var promise = get_resource($scope, CbgenRestangular, $stateParams.scheme_id);
promise.then(function (object) {
    console.log(object);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is **asychronous**. This is important to understand.
It means if you call a function which does an ajax call (a long running process), you need a callback.

Your code can't work because you have a function where you call another function. the second function then returns an object. but function 1 doesn't know that, so it return (undefined) immediately.

This should work.

```
get_resource = function ($scope, CbgenRestangular, id, _callback){
   CbgenRestangular.one('scheme', id).get().then(function(object){
      _callback(object);
 })
},

get_resource($scope, CbgenRestangular, $stateParams.scheme_id,function(_obj){
  console.log(obj)
});
```

By the way, you should never name a variable "object". This word is reserved..